# Post load image on tripadvisor make the widget move

Tags: javascript, image, tripadvisor

It's a pretty bizzare behavior, i have add the tripadvisor widget to this site : http://intermiel.com/fr/ high up in the top menu.... for week, maybe years, it's have been fine... NOW there is a post load script (?) that load a img 0px in size, that make the badge to move. i try to get the widget code again, and THIS IMG is not in the original code, it's added after.

this is the img code that cause problem

```
<img src="https://p.travelsmarter.net/api/usersync/seed.gif?api_key=gqLWKHSnTxes4YmmtgWkqA&amp;loc_id=3203440&amp;publisher_browser_id=edbf833c549700c33bb814721d4e1b6d348fdf32&amp;cb=1510760507695" alt="" width="0" height="0">
```

After trying to figure out way to fix it in css for 2-3 hours, i give up.

my question : is this normal, why it apprend ?, and how to fix it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something in generated code was changed, and probably some of you styles put margin or something. Do it simple:

```
#CDSWIDLNKR{top:-12px}
```

Comment: The problem is a line height of li element - another fix is
.topitem{line-height:0}

Or just hide img like: .TA_linkingWidgetRedesign img{display:none}

Comment: #CDSWIDLNKR{top:-12px} : DID NOT WORK because when you make it in the debugger the page is loader, but when you integrate it to the site, it dont work. SORRY !

Comment: .TA_linkingWidgetRedesign img{display:none} DID partially work, but hide image on the second line of the badge, so i cannot use it SORRY

Comment: .topitem{line-height:0} : WORK perfectly, change your answer to this, and i will approve it. THANKS !